# Add a variable to refer to a function

Tags: c++, visual-studio

this is my code in visual studio c++ ,

```
//draw a line onto the frame


        line(imgFrame2Copy, Point(0, imgFrame2Copy.rows / 2), Point(imgFrame2Copy.cols, imgFrame2Copy.rows / 2), Scalar(0), 3);
        //display the result

        line(imgFrame2Copy, Point(0, imgFrame2Copy.rows / 8), Point(imgFrame2Copy.cols, imgFrame2Copy.rows / 8), Scalar(0), 3);

        //wait some time for the frame to render
        waitKey(30);

        drawCarCountOnImage(carCount, imgFrame2Copy);


        cv::imshow("imgFrame2Copy", imgFrame2Copy);



        //cv::waitKey(0);                 // uncomment this line to go frame by frame for debugging

        // now we prepare for the next iteration
```

I want to add a variable to refer to the funtion `line(imgFrame2Copy, Point(0, imgFrame2Copy.rows / 2), Point(imgFrame2Copy.cols, imgFrame2Copy.rows / 2), Scalar(0), 3);`
   can you help me 
cordialy.

Comment: Checkout lambda expressions. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda.

Comment: When you say add a function? Can you clarify what you mean? In simplest terms you should be able to replace a parameter with the function name if it has a proper return type.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: this function line(imgFrame2Copy, Point(0, imgFrame2Copy.rows / 2), Point(imgFrame2Copy.cols, imgFrame2Copy.rows / 2), Scalar(0), 3); for drawing a line and i want to add to my code a variable wicth refence to this line

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to modern C++ (C++11 or later) you can use a lambda (as mentioned by R Sahu):

```
auto drawMyLine = [imgFrame2Copy](int denominator) {
    line(imgFrame2Copy,
         Point(0, imgFrame2Copy.rows / denominator),
         Point(imgFrame2Copy.cols, imgFrame2Copy.rows / denominator),
         Scalar(0),
         3);
  };

drawMyLine(2);
```

Note that by capturing what I assume is an OpenCV Matrix `cv::Mat` by value, you're making a copy of a reference counted object, so that lambda *should* be OK for the duration of its lifetime. That said, if you create too many of these, you may run out of memory ;-)

Otherwise, you can use a C++98-style functor:

```
struct DrawMyLine {
  void operator()(cv::Mat& imgFrame2Copy, int denominator) {
    line(imgFrame2Copy,
         Point(0, imgFrame2Copy.rows / denominator),
         Point(imgFrame2Copy.cols, imgFrame2Copy.rows / denominator),
         Scalar(0),
         3);
  }
};

DrawMyLine drawLine;
drawLine(imgFrame2Copy, 2);
```